# styling navigtion css margins

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have trouble to center align text (horisontal and vertical)
on the dynamic navigation buttons. The buttons have set with and height that
makes the button to have single or double line of text.
I want the text center align either if there is single or double-row of text.

Any easy CSS solution to fix that?
Right know I have styled the buttons with double line of text with `"top-margin"` manually (see css declaration below),

```
#access li#menu-item-21 a { 
 margin-top:3px; line-height:1.2em; height:27px;
}
```

But I dont want to set specific css declaration on the button with 2 rows of text.. I want to set same #access a  styling for all the buttons..Is that possible to achive this look?

link to  my page [a link]http://djbaba.se/navTest/

Should be a better way to solve that.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0081s4rc8b

Comment: This may be helpful for you: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `absolute` positioning and to set `top` to 50%.  Then set a negative top margin half the height of the element.

**Example**

```
#access li#menu-item-21 a {
     line-height: 1.2;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -12px; // half the height of the anchor
}
```

### Update

You could try using `display: table-cell`.

**Example**

```
a{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

Comment: thanx for you help! but I dont want to set specific css declaration on the button with 2 rows of text.. I want to set same #access a for all the buttons..is that possible to achive this look?